# rails ajax link from index.erb to show.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have never done ajax in rails, so I have no idea how to begin. What I want to do is, at top of scaffolding, I want the show links from index.erb to be ajax links that get the contents from the show action and ajax-ly put them in a div inside index.erb.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a href tag easily ajaxlable in rails , But depending on your rails version it slightly differ

if you are using rails < 3

use `link_to_remote`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote

if you are using rails > 3

you could use `link_to` tag with `:remote => true` option

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: how do I put the returned html into a div? I figured I need to use a js.erb page, what code should I put in it?

Comment: There are a couple of different schools of thought on this.  Check out: http://www.chadfowler.com/2011/02/09/how-rails-developers-do-ajax-with-jquery-in-2011  for a nice little survey of methods.  Choose what fits for you.